# Bootstrap 5 JavaScript function does not work on any pages

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5 in the asp.net core project, the CSS is being loaded properly but the javascript function is not working wherever the HTML property is placed on any pages.

In the example below I am using bootstrap tooltip, the bootstrap tooltip is not working, because no javascript bootstrap function is working here.

Similar is the case for nav-tab, carousel, and other bootstrap javascript functions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Classictravel</title>
    <link href="~/lib/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap-icons/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
    Tooltip on top
</button>
```

The tooltip doesn't function properly though there is no error in the console.

What is the proper way of using the bootstrap in the asp.net core project? Why is the bootstrap javascript function not working in my project?

What configuration I am missing here in my implementation?

When the mouse is over the tooltip, this is the output I get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the overview in the [document](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/tooltips/#overview).

Use `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` which contains `Popper.js` in layout:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Initialize all tooltips on the page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}


<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
    Tooltip on top
</button>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        })
    </script>
}
```

Comment: this is jquery I don't want to use jquery:
I had to add the following code to make that work.

`var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})`